# ListFeatureClasses brings back more than expected

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

Why, when I issue the function:

```
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type='point')
```

does it bring back a list of grid/rasters as well as all my point featureclasses from ArcSDE.  All I want is my **point** featureclasses, this doesn't make any sense!  Anyone had this happen to them? Plus it is incredibly slow!

Any help much appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried "**P**oint" instead of "**p**oint".  Case often matters.

Comment: Yep, tried both, same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to reply so late.  This is a bug.  The workaround below satisfied my needs (10.1).  Others ([esri link](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/15252-List-FC-vs-List-Rasters-Issues)) suggested using a Describe, but I found that too slow and unnecessary.

```
#Main call:  
for FC in bugListFeatureClasses("filter","feature type","feature dataset"):
    #do something

def bugListFeatureClasses(wildCard, fType, FD): 
    """
    Uses current workspace
    This is required because a 4 YEAR OLD BUG in arcpy still exists.
        arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() returns rasters
        Arc10 + SQL Server = apparently too complicated for Esri
        http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDYyMDc0 (must sign in first)
    """
    badFCList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(wildCard,fType,FD)
    rasList = [x.lower() for x in arcpy.ListRasters()]
    goodFCList = []
    for FC in badFCList:
        if FC.lower() not in rasList:
            goodFCList.append(FC)

    return goodFCList
```

Comment: Comments are great.

Answer (score 4):

You can emulate the example in the [ArcMap Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z00000011000000)
The code example from there does not have an = sign, just a wildcard and a feature type, as referenced there...

```py
# Set the workspace. List all of the polygon feature classes that 
#   start with 'G'
#
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/St_Johns/data.gdb"

fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("G*", "polygon")
```

Comment: Doesn't work, tried with just an "*" and "Point", it still brings back all point featureclasses and all grids.